# jQuery Slidetoggle Rotate 45deg and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, slidetoggle

I am trying to make the element rotate 45º on click action, the toggle element should open.
If you click on it again I want it to rotate back and the toggle element should close.

I have tried a lot of codes, I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

[Plugin I am using](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit)

jQuery:

```
$(".category-desc-toggle").click(function () {
    $('.category-desc').slideToggle(300);
    $(".category-desc-toggle").toggleClass("rotate45");
});
```

Css:

```
.rotate45 { 
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.category-desc-toggle { 
    -moz-transition: all .3s; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s; 
    -o-transition: all .3s; 
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way(Less code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed JuanT is right that CSS3 can accomplish the transformation, See [Firefox MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) for more info.

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7K6GP/4/**

```
<div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="category-desc-toggle rotate"></div>
    <div class="category-desc">Just Some Description</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(".description-wrapper").click(function() {
        $(this).children('div.category-desc').slideToggle(300);
        $(this).children('div.category-desc-toggle').toggleClass("rotate45");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you need to use that plugin if the CSS transition achieves the same purpose?

Comment: @Frank I've edited my answer for you & a new fiddle, hope that's what you're after

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your requirements, its hard to give you a full answer. Though, this can be accomplished with css3's rotate and transition property.

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

I have created a jsfiddle demonstrating this. http://jsfiddle.net/hGZbW/

EDIT:
If anyone is trying to accomplish this without CSS, there is a jquery plugin that supports most major browsers. To accomplish this affect for IE you would need to use the matrix filter.

https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki

Comment: Thanks man, I got it working, but is there anyway without useing css in style.css so we add it where the jquery runs. I add the Css in the edit

Comment: Frank, as an FYI I added a jquery plugin that can accomplish this rotation.